# SpingBoot Log file missing in deployed war (tomcat)

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

When I ran with the `java -jar` command, my LOG configuration came into effect. But when I deployed to an external tomcat container, I found that my LOG configuration was not in effect and the LOG files were lost.

I looked into a lot of questions and answers, found a tomcat LOG covered the default configuration, but I didn't find the way to solve the problem.

Here is my log configuration

```
logging.config=classpath:config/logging-config.xml
logging.path=src/main/resources/log
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening when running in outer tomcat, because the tomcat will set the logging.config properties into the system environment, and will override the spring default logging.config context file.

you can break on

```
org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener#initializeSystem
```

step into the `String logConfig = environment.getProperty(CONFIG_PROPERTY);`

then you can find the reason.

To solve this, you can run `System.setProperty("loggin.config", "you log file")` to override tomcat's logging.properties